# How do you find the inverse of a function defined by a derivative?

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

Suppose there is a function defined as $$f(x)= \frac{d}{dx}g(x)$$ similar to how $1/x$ is $ \frac{d}{dx}log(x)$ or $ \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $ \frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)$ or something along those lines. Is there a general process (probably using the inverse function theorem) to find $f^{-1}(x)$?

The reason I ask is because there are more difficult functions that may end up being defined this way that don't have immediately apparent relationships. You could for instance define $e^{-x^{2}}$ as $ \frac{d}{dx}erf(x)$.

Comment: @nikola That's not it. Take $g(x) = x^2$, for instance. Then $f(x) = 2x$ and $f^{-1}(x) = \frac12x$. That's not an antiderivative of $g$. Also, there is no need to be condecending. This site is for asking questions. The entire point is to help people learn. No matter the age or level of the asker.

Comment: Sorry, I am blind....

Answer (score 1):

I will assume everything is invertible and smooth, at least locally. The following holds for every $a$ and $b$.
$$
\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x)dx=bf(b)-af(a)-\int_a^b f(x)dx \\
=(bf(b)-g(b))-(af(a)-g(a))
$$
This can be easily seen by regarding the integration as the area of the region below the graph. You may also say that from the above equation, the antiderivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ is
$$
\int f^{-1} (x)dx = xf^{-1}(x)-g\circ f^{-1}(x)
$$
You can check the equality by differentiating both sides.